# React class tidy up

Tags: reactjs

I have created a class that selectively changes the className of a div element depending on what is passed to it.

Normally, I could do something like {(display ? "active" : "basic")} but as there is literally 5 different variations this doesn't seem practical...

Can anyone recommend how this could be restructured to perhaps be in just functional components or just tidier?

```
export default class ClickableAnswer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick(){
    if(this.props.display == true && this.props.clickable){
      this.props.handleClick(this.props.index);
    }
  }
  render() {
    let text = this.props.children;
    let divClass = "btn word basic";

    if(!this.props.clickable)
    {
        divClass = "btn word not_clickable";
    }
    else if(!this.props.display){
       divClass = "btn word active";
       text = "_";
    }
    else if(this.props.revealAnswer)
    {
        if(this.props.isCorrect)
        {
            divClass = "btn word correct";
        }
        else
        {
            divClass = "btn word incorrect";
        }
    }

    return (
      <div className={divClass} onClick={this.handleClick}>{text}</div>
    );
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As i don't know how you are calling `ClickableAnswer` component from parent, this would be a start for what i understood from your code:

```js
// An object that holds the possible classNames
const divClassName = {
  notClickable: "btn word not_clickable",
  wordActive: "btn word active",
  wordCorrect: "btn word correct",
  wordIncorrect: "btn word incorrect",
};

class ClickableAnswer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick(value) {
    if (
      this.props.displayAction &&
      this.props.displayAction !== "notClickable"
    ) {
      this.props.handleClick(value);
    }
  }
  render() {
    let text = this.props.children;

    // Get the className from divClassName Object based on 'displayAction'
    // If doesnt exists go with "btn word basic"
    let testClass = divClassName[this.props.displayAction] || "btn word basic";

    if (this.props.displayAction === "wordActive"){
        text = "_";
    }

    return (
      <div className={testClass} onClick={() => this.handleClick(this.props.displayAction)}>
        {text}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const App = () => {
  function handleClick(index) {
    console.log("index", index);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ClickableAnswer handleClick={handleClick}>TEST</ClickableAnswer>
       {/* set prop with the specific action */}
      <ClickableAnswer displayAction="wordActive" handleClick={handleClick}>
        TEST
      </ClickableAnswer>
      <ClickableAnswer displayAction="wordCorrect" handleClick={handleClick}>
        TEST 2
      </ClickableAnswer>
      <ClickableAnswer displayAction="wordIncorrect" handleClick={handleClick}>
        TEST 3
      </ClickableAnswer>
      <ClickableAnswer displayAction="notClickable" handleClick={handleClick}>
        TEST 4
      </ClickableAnswer>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<style>
 .not_clickable{
   color: orange;
 }
 .word.active{
   color: blue;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
 .word.incorrect{
   color: red;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
 .word.correct{
   color: green;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
</style>

<div id="root"></div>
```